# Django next/prev instance of a model with a certain condition?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to find next instance of an object model but with a certain condition.

Models.py:

```
class Pin(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I know `pk` of one instance to get the next instance I can do:

```
pin = Pin.objects.get(pk=123)
pin_next = pin.get_next_by_published()
```

But I want the next pin which has `price` not equal to null, so kind of an and condition. Next instance but with price not null. I can use a loop to keep on finding the next of next untill it has price not null. But is there any direct way?

Comment: I think that get_next_by and get_previous_by work only with dates. You'll probably have to write your own method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass additional lookup keyword args to the `get_next_by_XXX` methods, so in your above case `pin.get_next_by_published(price__isnull=False)` should work. If you have more complex conditions or want a non date-based ordering you'll have to write your own method.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write the query yourself but it's fairly trivial :)

Note that since `published` might not be unique this might not always work as you would expect. I would recommend `pk` based navigation because of that.

```
class Pin(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def others(self):
        return self.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)

    def others_with_price(self):
        return self.others().filter(price__isnull=False)

    # By primary key:

    def get_next(self):
        return self.others_with_price(pk__gt=self.pk).order_by('pk')[0]

    def get_prev(self):
        return self.others_with_price(pk__lt=self.pk).order_by('-pk')[0]

    # By published:

    def get_next_published(self):
        return self.others_with_price(published__gte=self.published).order_by('published')[0]

    def get_prev_published(self):
        return self.others_with_price(published__lte=self.published).order_by('-published')[0]
```

Comment: This wont order on `published` - and will only order on pk if not ordering is specified in the model's `Meta`.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers I think the OP wants to get next pin by price, regardless of publishing date. That is how I have understood it.

Comment: @cezar that's not what I understood - he explicitely mentions "next pin" as being returned by `get_next_by_published()`, and do not ask how to "get next pin by another ordering", only how to filter out pins that don't have a price.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers When I read that again, you seem to have right.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Rather elaborate method but Bruno's answer is what I was looking for.